# JSP gets loaded each time ajax call is made

Tags: java, ajax, jsp

Im creating Hang man in which text fields appear whose number is equal to the number of characters in word to be guessed. There is a seperate text field in which user types in a character which then goes to the servlet through an ajax call on a button click. Here is my jsp code

```
<body>
        <%        //Input streams for file read
        File dictionary= new File("D:\\FatimaArshad05241/Dictionary.txt");
        FileReader fr= new FileReader(dictionary);
        LineNumberReader ln= new LineNumberReader(fr);
       RandomAccessFile raf = new RandomAccessFile(dictionary, "r");
        //counter to count number of lines
        int counter=0;
        //count number of lines
        while(ln.readLine()!=null){
        counter++;
        }
        //generate a random line number
       Random rnmber = new Random();
       int line=1+rnmber.nextInt(counter);
       String word="";
       int c=1;
       //position pointer to the top of file
       word= raf.readLine();
        raf.seek(0);
       //fetch the word
      while(raf!=null){

        if(c==line){
             //System.out.println("oh here");
             break;

        }
        else{

          word=  raf.readLine();

            }

         c++;

        }
      char[] array= new char[200];
      System.out.println("The word is");
      System.out.println(word);
      counter=0;
      for(int i=0; i<word.length();i++){
        array[i]= word.charAt(i);
        counter++;
      }
      %>
        <% for(int i=0; i<counter;i++){%>
            <input type="text" name="<%=i%>" id="<%=i%>"/>
            <%}%>
        <form>

                <br/>   
                 <br/> 
                  <br/> 
           <input type="text" name="t" id="t"/>
           <input type="button" name="a" id="a" value="enter"/>


       </form>


        <script>
            $("#a").click(
            function(e){
                var wordguessed= $("#t").val();
                $.GET("HangMan.java",{word:<%=word%>,wordguessed=wordguessed}, function(data,value){

                <%System.out.println("so u did it :p");%>

                alert(data);

            });

            }        
            );

        </script>


    </body>
```

The problem with this one is that ajax is successful and when the button is pressed, jsp page is reloaded and new word is given. Statements in servlet side are not executed at all. Here is my Servlet code

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {

        System.out.println("So the word guessed khhftuuuuuuuuuuygyhhgis");
           String word= request.getParameter("word");
           String wordguessed= request.getParameter("wordguessed");
           System.out.println("So the word guessed is"+wordguessed);

        }
```

I dont want JSP to be reloaded again. Is there something Im missing?

Comment: Are you sure that the JS is even being called?

Comment: Strange name for a servlet `HangMan.java`

Comment: @ScaryWombat statement in ajax success function is executed

Comment: Can you tell us how you know.  The name of your servlet is strange, using `%=word%` in JS is also strange.

Comment: examine the produced HTML

Comment: @ScaryWombat Then how am I supposed to change it? I want to pass a variable word which is in Java code

Comment: a new word is generated again

Comment: write it as a hidden text field with an id that you can call from JS

Comment: consider re-designing your code, so that the servlet (initially) loads the text file and puts in into a LIST, add this to your session, use STL in the JSP to loop through this.  Code in JSP is a NO-NO